# how to get an Object fields

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jsf, object

i am using a join sql in hibernate and i had to return a `List<object>`.
In the `xhtml`, i get to the fields using : `list[0],list[1]...` in my datatable

```
 <p:dataTable id="display" var="listeFactures" value="#{factureBean.listeFactures}" editable="true" style="margin-bottom:10px" rowKey="#{listeFactures[0]}" selection="#{factureBean.facture}" selectionMode="single">
       <f:facet name="header">
           Liste des devis
       </f:facet>
       <p:column headerText="N° Facture">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{listeFactures[0]}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{listeFactures[0]}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
```

now, in order to edit the fields i select on row and it gets me an Object 
so i access in the same way using the index `factureBean.facture[0]`
but in my bean i don't know how i could get the value that i've changed bacause it's an object. usualy if it's a specific one like `Facture` i use `getFacture().getIdFacture()` to get the id changed.
If someone have an idea how to do this, i appreciate your help
**edit :**
this is Facture.java

```
package net.vo;

import java.util.Date;

public class Facture  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private int idFacture;
     private Bondecommande bondecommande;
     private Rubrique rubrique;
     private Date dateFacture;
     private double montantFacture;
     private String etatFacture;

    public Facture() {
    }


    public Facture(int idFacture, Bondecommande bondecommande, Rubrique rubrique) {
        this.idFacture = idFacture;
        this.bondecommande = bondecommande;
        this.rubrique = rubrique;
    }
    public Facture(int idFacture, Bondecommande bondecommande, Rubrique rubrique, Date dateFacture, double montantFacture, String etatFacture) {
       this.idFacture = idFacture;
       this.bondecommande = bondecommande;
       this.rubrique = rubrique;
       this.dateFacture = dateFacture;
       this.montantFacture = montantFacture;
       this.etatFacture = etatFacture;
    }

    public int getIdFacture() {
        return this.idFacture;
    }

    public void setIdFacture(int idFacture) {
        this.idFacture = idFacture;
    }
    public Bondecommande getBondecommande() {
        return this.bondecommande;
    }

    public void setBondecommande(Bondecommande bondecommande) {
        this.bondecommande = bondecommande;
    }
    public Rubrique getRubrique() {
        return this.rubrique;
    }

    public void setRubrique(Rubrique rubrique) {
        this.rubrique = rubrique;
    }
    public Date getDateFacture() {
        return this.dateFacture;
    }

    public void setDateFacture(Date dateFacture) {
        this.dateFacture = dateFacture;
    }
    public double getMontantFacture() {
        return this.montantFacture;
    }

    public void setMontantFacture(double montantFacture) {
        this.montantFacture = montantFacture;
    }
    public String getEtatFacture() {
        return this.etatFacture;
    }

    public void setEtatFacture(String etatFacture) {
        this.etatFacture = etatFacture;
    }

}
```

Dao

```
@Override
    public List<Object> getAllFactures(int annee,int rubrique,int fournisseur) {
        Session session=HibernateUtil.getSession();
        try
        {
            session.beginTransaction();
            Rubrique r = daoR.getRubrique(rubrique);
            Fournisseur f = daoF.getFournisseur(fournisseur);
            Query q = session.createQuery("select f.idFacture,f.dateFacture,f.montantFacture,f.etatFacture,b.creditOuvert,b.creditReporte from Facture f,Budgetisation b,Rubrique r where year(f.dateFacture)=b.id.annee and f.rubrique=:rubrique and f.rubrique=r.idRubrique and r.idRubrique = b.rubrique and year(f.dateFacture)=:annee and f.bondecommande.devis.fournisseur=:fournisseur");
           q.setParameter("fournisseur", f);
          q.setParameter("rubrique", r);
         q.setParameter("annee", annee);
            listeFactures = q.list();
            return listeFactures;
        }
        catch(HibernateException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you post your `Facture` class? Why access your attributes as `listeFactures[0]` instead of `listeFactures.idFacture` ?

Comment: because what i get from the dao is a list of objects not a list of factures. so i can't access it in this way listeFactures.idFacture. if you could tell me how i could make my sql join not return Object. i will edit the post @rion18

Comment: Have you tried changing `listeFactures = q.list();` to `listeFactures = (List<Facture>q.list();` ?, then the method could return a List of Facture.

Answer (score 0):

You will get `List<Object[]>` instead of `List<Object>` while you will get list of records(object[]) which consist columns(single object).

Comment: my response didn't show well: what i wanna say is  instead of using this way of joining. i use now left join and it gets me the List<Facture> not List<Object> @Peter Wroblewski